# Popping lists - Typical Sock Pairs Question (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I've been set with the following task:

Write a function that returns the number of sock pairs. A sock pair consists of two of the same letter, such as "AA". The socks are represented as an unordered sequence.

SockPairs("AABB") ➞ 1

My code.. doesn't work. I'm trying to use the pop method to populate a new list for the letter A, but I can't get it to such a thing.

I've been working on this since like 6AM this morning, my brain is fried from University reports (lol). Can anyone give me any advice to achieve such a solution to my code?

All I want is to see if my new list will populate if the character "A" exists in my original list.

If anyone has any solution to my problem I'd be eternally grateful.

```
mySocks = ("AA")
mySocks = list(mySocks)

popped_ar = []
popped_ar = mySocks.pop()

A = []

while len(mySocks) != 0:
    for x in A:
        if "A" in popped_ar:
            A.append(mySocks.pop())



print (A)
```

Comment: Whats your input( is it just AA or something else) and expected output?

Comment: Input, for now, is just AABB, I want to be able to create a whole new list for each character.

Comment: Well, each UNIQUE character

Comment: @ggorlen you're correct. Editing mistake on my behalf.

Comment: Can you show me expected output? The pair should be next to each other?

Comment: For example, `AABAB`'s pair is `A` and `B`? or only `A`?

Comment: @BrógánMcShane Replacing your original code with a working solution sort of negates the question for future visitors who will have no idea what the problem was with your implementation. I rolled back to the last edit.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for letting me know this. I am not-so-good at posting here.

Comment: That's OK, everyone starts out that way. Good question otherwise.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks man, very encouraging to hear. Enjoy your day boss :)

Answer (score 4):

[Collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) makes tasks like this easy:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> socks = "ACABBACBBAACCDDB"
>>> sum(x // 2 for x in Counter(socks).values())
7
```

This works by first mapping every letter to a count of its occurrences. After that, floor divide each occurrence count by two, so 8 becomes 4 and 7 becomes 3 (we can't make a pair with an odd number). Take the sum.

Without collections, this is the same as:

```
socks = "ACABBACBBAACCDDB"
counts = {}

for sock in socks:
    if sock not in counts:
        counts[sock] = 0

    counts[sock] += 1

pairs = sum(x // 2 for x in counts.values())
```

Comment: I would like to populate each character into its own list. So every A will be stored in an A list, B in another, C in another... Can you help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
socks = "ABCAMMCSAASBB"
socks_counter = dict()

# Count the number of socks of each type
for sock in socks:
    if sock in socks_counter:
        socks_counter[sock] += 1
    else:
        socks_counter[sock] = 1

# Prepare the socks pairs
for key in socks_counter:
    socks_counter[key] = socks_counter[key] // 2

print("Number of socks pairs for each type:", socks_counter)
print("Total pairs of socks:", sum(socks_counter.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
Number of socks pairs for each type: {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'M': 1, 'S': 1}
Total pairs of socks: 6
```